# MongoDB find Query for array data with object value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am stuck with monogodb query build and data find into array object value.

in this array if i get specific object of specific value get

Ex:

```
-->in department --> "5a6589d94abd7408c36350da" --> "received"
```

if "received" value is false then it will return whole document.

My data Object is Here.

```
{"_id": "5cff4d893d900862be52cac5",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "duration": 8,
                    "user": null,
                    "department": [
                        {
                            "5a6589834abd7408c36350d9": {
                                "skiped": false,
                                "completed_date": "2019-06-11T06:36:09.431Z",
                                "completed": true,
                                "received_date": "2019-06-11T06:36:09.431Z",
                                "received": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "5a6589d94abd7408c36350da": {
                                "skiped": false,
                                "completed_date": "2019-06-26T09:36:52.975Z",
                                "completed": true,
                                "recieved_date": "2019-06-11T06:43:21.590Z",
                                "received": false,
                                "totalDaysofCompletion": 15,
                                "user_id": "5b3c629a250d3a65eb7367a5"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "5a658b054abd7408c36350db": {
                                "skiped": false,
                                "completed_date": "2019-06-11T06:36:09.431Z",
                                "completed": false,
                                "received_date": "2019-06-26T09:36:52.980Z",
                                "received": true
                            }
                        }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first retrieve document by _id then check received value .
or you can find document by passing _id and received value false if received value of that document is false it will return null other wise it will return document.

Query for multiple argument can help you.
`department.find({"_id" : "5a6589d94abd7408c36350da" , "received" : false })`

Comment: i want to find inside of department array with his object and inside of that object check value.

Comment: you are using mongoose to interact with mongodb? please provide some details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection("demo_table").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$department"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }, 
            "department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da.received" : false
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "department" : 1.0
        }
    }
]
);
```

Comment: in robo3t i fire query like this:

` db.getCollection('tasks').find({ 'department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da.recieved' : true, 'department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da.completed' : false })  `


and It's work

Comment: Using 'find' won't work, you need to use 'aggregate' in your scenario.

Comment: i do like that but, still not return any data

`Task.aggregate(
    [
      { $lookup: {
          from: _TaskDetail.collection.name,
          localField: 'details',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'details'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$details'
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          "path": "$department"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da": {
            $exists: true
          },
          "department.5a6589d94abd7408c36350da.received": true
        }
      }
    ]
  )`

Comment: Hey... I got solution....

`
let c = "5a6589d94abd7408c36350da";
let Qry = {};
  Qry[`department.${c}.recieved`] = true;
  Qry[`department.${c}.completed`] = false;
  console.log(Qry)
  return Task.find(Qry).exec();`

I use like this and it's work.